# Creating Change Bars Using XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a document and I need to track changes using revision bars (black bars in the margin to indicate where changes have taken place).

The changed text is done using `<span class="changeText">`.

Example code, below:

```
<p>This is the original text. This is the original text. This is the original text. This
is the original text. This is the original text. <span class="changeText">This text has
changed. This text has changed. This text has changed.</span> This is the original text.
</p>
```

[image]

I can get reasonably close by using

```
fo:block background-color="lightyellow" border-end-color="black"
border-start-style="solid" border-start-width="4pt" padding-start="25pt"
```

Of course, that treats the section as a block. I need to make it work inline... but have not been able to figure out the right code to provide this type of behavior having the text flow inline.

Any thoughts our input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Most FO processors support change bars native as it is not as easy as you present especially when it comes to page ends and such. So first, specify which FO processor

Comment: Hi Daniel and Kevin - we are currently using Apache FOP... but based on TMakita's answer below - it looks like I might be out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

The revision bar can be realized using `fo:change-bar` and `fo:change-bar-end` in XSL-FO.

6.13.2 fo:change-bar-begin

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_change-bar-begin

6.13.3 fo:change-bar-end

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_change-bar-end

So it is needed to generate `fo:change-bar-begin`, `fo:inline` and `fo:change-bar-end` from `<span class="changeText">` element at once such like following template:

```
<xsl:template match="span[string(@class) eq 'changeText']">
    <xsl:variable name="id" as="xs:string" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    <fo:change-bar-begin change-bar-class="{$id}" change-bar-color="black" change-bar-style="solid"/>
    <fo:inline background-color="yellow">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
    <fo:change-bar-end change-bar-class="{$id}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The sample result:

[image]

This is generated by AH Formatter. Unfortunately FOP does not implement `fo:change-bar-begin` and `fo:change-bar-end` at this moment.

Comment: FOP was implemented fo:change-bar-begin and fo:change-bar-end in the version FOP 2.4: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/changes_2.4.html